# Как правильно организовать работу серверов frontend + backend?

Tags: node.js, frontend, клиент-сервер, backend, аутентификация

У меня есть уже backend(далее: **backendBusiness**), в котором прописана логика аутентификации, делаются запросы к БД, соответственно, и еще немного по мелочи. Frontend был просто набором разным html-страничек с одним большим скриптом для всего. Теперь frontend-часть рисуется с помощью node.js + express(далее: **backendHtml**). Я правильно понимаю, что мне все, что касается шаблонизаторов(**backendHtml**), надо прикрутить непосредственно к **backendBusiness**, прям слить воедино? Или необходимо их вести отдельно и общение между ними должно быть дополнительной прослойкой get/post запросов? В данный момент я поднял для этого отдельный сервер.
В итоге, у меня есть 2 сервера, которые не взаимосвязаны. Как правильно мне теперь объединить их?

Конкретный пример: Шаблонизатор используется, допустим, для динамической перерисовки шапки сайта с именем пользователя, который залогинился на сайте(использую Json web tokens). Раньше с фронта у меня просто отправлялся запрос на бэк, и посредством JS при авторизации перерисовывалась эта шапка.

В голове есть 2 варианта(на примере аутентификации):

1. 2 backend-сервера будут слиты в один. При удачной попытке зайти в свой аккаунт - будет выполняться дополнительная логика на сервере. Но здесь вопрос скорее в архитектурно правильном построении всего этого. Фактически,+ все запросы на старый backend надо будет убирать и вынести их как бы в функцию, которая будет запускаться, когда нужен будет тот или иной шаблон?
2. С клиентского браузера отправлять запрос на backend([www.backend.com/login](http://www.backend.com/login)). После логики на сервере приходит ответ в клиентский браузер с подтверждением(вход удался) - потом клиентский браузер перенаправляет эти данные на frontend-сервер для перерисовки контента.
   P.S: и я понимаю, что это совсем не оптимизированный вариант. Можно даже сказать, неадекватный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос получился все же довольно-таки расплывчатый. Однако. Решение такое:

Я объединил 2 сервера в один. Все данные о пользователе(при условии работы с JWT), где это необходимо, берутся либо из самого payload в провалидированном JWT, либо, если необходимо расширенная информация о пользователе, из базы данных, поиск в которой осуществляется по найденным данным в том же JWT.

Вот конкретный пример со страничкой /profile:

```
  app.get("/profile",
    (request, response, next) => validateTokenAccessBind(request, response, next, false),
    (request, response) => {
      const user = request.user;
      const isUser = request.isUser;

      if(isUser) {
        response.render("profile", {
          title: "Profile page",
          mainContainerClass: mainContainerTypes["body-container-main"],
          userData: { // todo mock value(helpers)
            exist: true,
            name: user.name,
            imagePath: user.imagePath || "/fake"
          }
        })
      }
      else {
        response.render("profile", {
          title: "Profile page",
          mainContainerClass: mainContainerTypes["body-container-main"],
          userData: { // todo mock value(helpers)
            exist: false,
            name: "",
            imagePath: "/fake",
          }
        })
      }
  })
```

В свою очередь, midlleware "validateTokenAccessBind" содержит следующий код:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
// own modules
const setCookies = require("./setCookies");

dotenv.config();

function validateToken(secretToken, nameField, request, response, next, isThrowOnError = true) {
  const token = request.cookies[nameField];
  if (token == null || token == undefined || token === "") {
    if(isThrowOnError) {
      response.sendStatus(400);
      return;
    }
    else {
      setCookies(response, [
        {
          "isAuthenticate": false,
          modifyOptions: {
            httpOnly: false
          }
        }
      ])
      request.isUser = false;

      next();
      return;
    }
  }

  jwt.verify(token, secretToken, (error, user) => {
    if (error) {
      setCookies(response, [
        {
          [nameField]: "",
          modifyOptions: {
            maxAge: 0
          }
        },
        {
          "isAuthenticate": false,
          modifyOptions: { 
            httpOnly: false
          }
        }
      ])

      if(isThrowOnError) {
        response.status(403).json({
          message: "token invalid"
        });
      }
      else {
        request.isUser = false;

        next();
      }
    }
    else {
      request.isUser = true;
      request.user = user;

      next();
    }
  })
}

const validateTokenAccessBind = validateToken.bind(null, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, "accessToken");
const validateTokenRefreshBind = validateToken.bind(null, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, "refreshToken");

module.exports = validateToken;
module.exports = {validateTokenAccessBind, validateTokenRefreshBind};
```

Таким образом, если при проверке в middleware оказывается, что токен не подошел, либо его совсем нет, то у нас не вылетает ошибка, а рендерится нужная страничка, благодаря аргументу "isThrowOnError" ставится флаг:

```
request.isUser = false;
```

Затем, уже идет логика на стороне клиента. В данном случае используется страничка "/profile". Там необходимо, чтобы user был аутентифицирован. Соответственно, просто с помощью, например

```
window.location.href = "/login";
```

перебрасываем незнакомого нам пользователя на вход в наш сервис.

P.S: setCookies - это лишь собственная функция, которая отправляет cookie пользователю в удобном для меня формате.